# MATLAB: Saving all tabs of a docked figure in a single .fig file

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a matlab figure with 4 tabs that are generated inside a for loop. The figure handles are overwritten for each tab inside the loop. I want to save this figure window as it is (with the 4 tabs in single figure window), but with the savefig() command(used outside the loop) I'm only able to save the last tab. With the savefig(handle,_) command used inside the loop(along with a close(handle) outside the loop), I'm able to save in a single file, but the tabs open in separate figure windows. Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you store the handle to the parent of the tab group to use with `savefig()` it should also save all the child objects.

For example:

```
h.mainfig = figure();
h.tabgroup = uitabgroup(h.mainfig, 'Position', [.05 .1 .9 .8]);

ntabs = 4;

for ii = 1:ntabs
    h.tab(ii) = uitab(h.tabgroup, 'Title', sprintf('Tab_%i', ii));
end

% Make a sample plot on tab 2
h.axes(2) = axes('Parent', h.tab(2));
plot(h.axes(2), 1:10);

savefig(h.mainfig, 'test.fig');
```

Opening `test.fig` should reopen the entire figure.

As a general aside I would recommend *not* overwriting things as you create them, it makes it a pain to address later on and you don't really gain anything by overwriting them with each iteration.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you also add on on how to use the figure handle to include subplots within each tab? If I plot something it goes behind the tabs.

Comment: You need to create `axes` objects and make sure their `Parent` property is set to the tab you'd like them to be displayed on. By saving these axes handles you can plot to them specifically later on in your code. I have updated my answer to include a sample.

Comment: Can you do this from the figure GUI?

Comment: @NikoTumi You can do it from wherever you'd like, you just need the figure handle.